# Would a headwind result in a faster propeller rpm?

Tags: propeller, crosswind

A few weeks ago I did an experiment with a model aircraft that has a motorized propeller. I turned on the propeller and it turned at a constant speed. Then I turned on a desk fan and put it in front of the propeller (see the picture below) and I saw an increase in propeller rpm and an increase in noise.

Does this also happen to a propeller when a headwind hits it?

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify this a lot.  `active propeller` - what is this?  `I turned on the propeller` - so it's driven by a motor? `propeller remained at a constant speed` - how did you measure it?   `30% increase in thrust` - how do you know?  How did you measure it?  If the aircraft was spinning in a circle, how could the fan generate a crosswind?  The ultimate answer is that all a crosswind does is to change the vector of the relative airflow hitting the propellor blades.

Comment: @Simon its an estimate.it was also on the floor it had no strings attached to it. Wasn't spinning in a circle. I will upload a picture soom

Comment: How was the thrust vector of the propeller oriented relative to the wind from the fan?

Comment: @Simon Made some edits so you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @mins Made some edits hope you can understand it now.

Comment: Did you put the fan *beside* the propeller to simulate a crosswind?

Comment: The edit definitely helps to clear things up. But it's still not clear how you are measuring thrust.

Comment: What you have pictured is a headwind, not a crosswind. A crosswind would be if you're blowing the aircraft from the side. Which are you wondering about?

Comment: Is the propellor free wheeling?

Comment: By faster, I suppose you mean you saw the propeller rotating faster. Feel free to reverse my edit if that's not what you meant.

Comment: @kevin it spun faster and it was louder. Great edits.

Comment: Are you sure the increase in noise came from the propeller, not from turning on the fan? Unless you have a pretty ( _extremely_ ) sophisticated audio set up, you'd be pretty hard pressed to tell the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you're holding the aircraft with your hand.

Imagine a windmill. It has no power at all, it spins freely. What happens when wind is blowing at it? It turns.

Now imagine a propeller with no power connected to it, so it acts like a windmill. If wind is blowing at it, it will turn just the same. Why? Because a propeller pushes wind backward when it turns. When it is facing a headwind, the propeller *wants* to turn such that it is pushing air at the same speed as the arriving air.

In your case, I suppose the fan is blowing air at a faster speed, compared to the propeller is pushing air on its motor. Say the motor pushes air backward at 1 m/s. The fan blows air at 2 m/s. That's why it spins faster with the fan on.

---

But that's only true as long as you're holding the aircraft with your hand.

In flight, nothing is holding the aircraft at a constant ground speed. For example, assume in a no wind condition, an aircraft is flying at 80 knots. Suddenly it encounters a 10 knots headwind, and continues to fly into this headwind for the remainder of the flight. What happens?

At the moment of encountering the headwind, the airspeed indicator in the cockpit *jumps* from 80 to 90. The propeller rpm will also suddenly jump to a higher value. But that is not going to last. The aircraft is getting pushed backward by the wind, the airspeed is going to slowly drop back to 80. ***There is not enough power to keep the propeller at the higher rpm which pushes air at 90, it can only to 80.*** After a while, it is flying at 80 knots relative to the air, and 70 knots relative to the ground.

Comment: would you care to comment on another situation - do you think a 3-blade prop would outperform a 2-blade prop in windshear situations? For example, if you were to fly missions ~3k AGL over peaks of mountains would you prefer a 3-blade prop, assuming the engine power is sufficient (260hp Lycoming mounted on RV-10). The question of 3 vs 2 blades often appears on various forums and majority of answers focus on top-speed where a 2-blade is marginally better, but I'm not concerned with the top-speed.

Answer (score 4):

A propeller is always facing a headwind, it's called "airspeed". I don't really know what to tell you, the wind relative to the ground doesn't matter to the airplane or the propeller, the wind hitting it head on does, and yes, as the airspeed increases the load on the prop is reduced and the RPM increases unless you have a constant speed propeller (and thus a governor that changes the pitch of the blade when the RPM increases to combat this).

A wind shear does indeed change the airspeed momentarily (more so for larger aircraft with more momentum), but so does pitching over and diving.

The net effect is that a "headwind" (as measured relative to the earth) will only affect your ground speed, and thus the time it takes to get to your destination. The headwind, as measured relative to the aircraft, is called airspeed, and is usually kept at some set value appropriate for the aircraft in cruise. If the airspeed increases abruptly, the RPM will increase slightly as the load decreases (air doesn't have to be accelerated as much), which is countered by the prop governor (if you have one) and the fact that the airplane will slow down to match the new headwind since you're not feeding it any more power to maintain the new higher airspeed.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the answer is yes for geared engines.

With geared engines, the propeller has enough mechanical advantage to drive the gearbox (rather than the engine driving the gearbox). This can hurt the gearbox and the engine.

The Rotax engine employs a built-in 2.4:1 reduction gearbox. When descending, you are not supposed to reduce power, otherwise the propeller will push on the gearbox and the engine (rather than the engine turning the gearbox and then the prop).